# Gradle Build Failed after updating android studio from 3.6.1 to 3.6.2

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.6.1

I have recently updated my ide and when I tried to run my old code that I have written before updating ide, it started showing a message that is below:

FAILURE:Build failed with a exception.

- What went wrong: Execution failed for the task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:appt2:3.6.2-6040484.   Required by:
  >         project :app
  >   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:appt2:3.6.2-6040484 available for offline mode.
  >   No cached version of com.android.tools.build.appt2:3.6.2-6040484 available for offline mode.

So what's the problem in it and one more thing is that I have enabled the toggle offline mode and even after connecting to the network it's not running and showing the same message.
Plz reply soon.

Comment: plz reply anyone

Comment: I guess you should Connect to internet and sync gradle ...

Comment: already done but same message is showing